# executing a function deep within arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hi I seem to be having problems executing a function deep within arrays:

```
var Segments = [Segment_1];

var Segment_1 = {
  "requirements": {
    "Dektec": "True",
    "SSH": "True"
  },
  "requests": {
    "R11": "True"
  },
  'function': function(){
     print("Hello World!");
  }
};


Segments[0]['function']();
```

This works if I am only one array deep though:

```
var Segments = [Segment_1];

function Segment_1() {
    print("Hello World!");
}

Segments[0]();
```

I have seen similar questions in Stackoverflow, but all pertaining to single level array. Any idea to what I am doing wrong here? I'm sure it is something simple.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EnvXc/), if you just move the definition of your array to after the definition of the member you are trying to put in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `Segments` after you set `Segment_1`

```
var Segment_1 = {
    "requirements": {
        "Dektec": "True",
        "SSH": "True"
    },
    "requests": {
        "R11": "True"
    },
    'function': function(){
        document.write("Hello World!");
    }
};

var Segments = [Segment_1]
```

You set `Segments` before you define `Segment_1`, therefore it is undefined.